# creating an alias on event after saving content with rules in drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-rules

I have created two rules 
In 1st rules

event :-After saving a new user account

condition:-
User has role(s)
Parameter: User: [account], Roles: teacher.

Action:- 
Create a new entity
Parameter: Entity type: Node, Content type: teacher`s profiles, Title: [account:name], Author: [account]
Provides variables: Created entity (entity_created)

And In second rules:-

I have taken following things:-

Event:-After saving new content.
condition:- 
Content is of type
Parameter: Content: [node], Content types: teacher`s profiles.

Action:- 
Create or delete a content's URL alias
Parameter: Content: [node], URL alias: node/[site:current-user]/edit.

The First rule Work perfectly But the problem is in second rules 
it create an alias with the **url: node/anonymous/edit**

I don`t know what is the problem in this rule anyone can help me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There must be an option for 'Operating user' or 'Current user'. if the user creates the event as visitors and no values is provided for the 'user', it will, of course, take 'anonymous'!

Comment: Thanks for reply yes their is a token available in drupal on node:author:name.  thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

In place of token `[site:current-user]`, you have to use token `[node:author:name]`.